# CheckBox values / no MVVM Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a group of check boxes and i need them to change value.. if one is checked the other should be unchecked. The reason why dont want to implement MVVM is that this is just new frontend for already existing application, i just need these to work before we merge projects. This what i have and it doesnt work,i get null reference / System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

I have this in my code

```
private void AdvancedCheckBox_IsCheckedChanged(object sender, IsCheckedChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (AdvancedCheckBox.IsChecked == true) //System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
            {
                AllCheckBox.IsChecked = false;
                UpperIntermediateCheckBox.IsChecked = false;
                AdvancedCheckBox.IsChecked = false;

            }
            else
                AdvancedCheckBox.IsChecked = true;
        }

        private void UpperIntermediateCheckBox_IsCheckedChanged(object sender, IsCheckedChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (UpperIntermediateCheckBox.IsChecked == true)
            {
                AllCheckBox.IsChecked = false;
                UpperIntermediateCheckBox.IsChecked = false;
                AdvancedCheckBox.IsChecked = false;

            }
            else
                UpperIntermediateCheckBox.IsChecked = true;
        }

        private void IntermediateCheckBox_IsCheckedChanged(object sender, IsCheckedChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            CheckBox IntermediateCheckBox = sender as CheckBox;
            if (IntermediateCheckBox.IsChecked == false)
            {
                AllCheckBox.IsChecked = false;
                UpperIntermediateCheckBox.IsChecked = false;
                AdvancedCheckBox.IsChecked = false ;

            }
            else
                IntermediateCheckBox.IsChecked = true ;
        }

        private void AllCheckBox_IsCheckedChanged(object sender, IsCheckedChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            CheckBox AllCheckBox = sender as CheckBox;
            if (AllCheckBox.IsChecked == true) System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
            {

                UpperIntermediateCheckBox.IsChecked = false;
                AdvancedCheckBox.IsChecked = false;
                IntermediateCheckBox.IsChecked = false;
            }
            else
                AllCheckBox.IsChecked = true;
        }
```

and my xaml

```
<StackLayout Grid.Row="0"
                            Orientation="Horizontal"
                            Spacing="10"
                            HorizontalOptions="Start">
                    <grial:Checkbox x:Name="AllCheckBox"
                            IsCheckedChanged ="AllCheckBox_IsCheckedChanged"
                            HorizontalOptions="Start">
                        <Label
                            Margin="10,0"
                            FontSize="19"
                            Text="{ grial:Translate A_LabelAllArticles}"
                            VerticalOptions="Center"
                            TextColor="{ DynamicResource AccentColor }" />
                    </grial:Checkbox>

                </StackLayout>
                <StackLayout  Grid.Row="1"
                            Orientation="Horizontal"
                            Spacing="10"
                            HorizontalOptions="Start">
                    <grial:Checkbox x:Name="BeginnerCheckBox"
                        IsChecked="false"
                        HorizontalOptions="Start">
                        <Label
                            FontSize="19"
                             Margin="10,0"
                            Text="{ grial:Translate A_LabelBeginnerArticles}"
                            VerticalOptions="Center"
                            TextColor="{ DynamicResource AccentColor }" />
                    </grial:Checkbox>

                </StackLayout>
                <StackLayout  Grid.Row="2"
                            Orientation="Horizontal"
                            Spacing="10"
                            HorizontalOptions="Start">
                    <grial:Checkbox x:Name="IntermediateCheckBox"
                            IsCheckedChanged="IntermediateCheckBox_IsCheckedChanged"
                            HorizontalOptions="Start">
                        <Label
                            FontSize="19"
                            Margin="10,0"
                            Text="{ grial:Translate A_LabelIntermediateArticles}"
                            VerticalOptions="Center"
                            TextColor="{ DynamicResource AccentColor }" />
                    </grial:Checkbox>

                </StackLayout>
                <StackLayout  Grid.Row="3"
                            Orientation="Horizontal"
                            Spacing="10"
                            HorizontalOptions="Start">
                    <grial:Checkbox x:Name="UpperIntermediateCheckBox"
                            IsCheckedChanged="UpperIntermediateCheckBox_IsCheckedChanged"
                            HorizontalOptions="Start">
                        <Label
                            FontSize="19"
                            Margin="10,0"
                            Text="{ grial:Translate A_LabelUpperIntermediateArticles}"
                            VerticalOptions="Center"
                            TextColor="{ DynamicResource AccentColor }" />
                    </grial:Checkbox>

                </StackLayout>
                <StackLayout  Grid.Row="4"
                            Orientation="Horizontal"
                            Spacing="10"
                            HorizontalOptions="Start">
                    <grial:Checkbox x:Name="AdvancedCheckBox"
                        IsCheckedChanged="AdvancedCheckBox_IsCheckedChanged"
                            HorizontalOptions="Start">
                        <Label
                            FontSize="19"
                            Margin="10,0"
                            Text="{ grial:Translate A_LabelAdvancedArticles}"
                            VerticalOptions="Center"
                            TextColor="{ DynamicResource AccentColor }" />
                    </grial:Checkbox>
```

Comment: your first three methods have identical statements within the IF - that does not seem correct

Comment: yes, i was trying different approaches

Comment: I have added an anwser, but i don't have much context on what is causing the nullexception, can you add that information to que question? i will glady update my anwser if it needs to

Comment: @Ricardo Dias Morais Hi, this seems great. But I am getting the same exception. I guess I am missing something.This is underlined and (ClickedCheckbox.IsChecked != null ? this is the output the result is always null since its never equal to null of type bool

Comment: @Ricardo Dias Morais  bool WasSelected = ClickedCheckbox.IsChecked != null ? ClickedCheckbox.IsChecked != null : false; System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Comment: Wait... grial:Checkbox , is this the Native Xamarin.Forms Checkbox? or is it from a plugin?

Comment: see my updated anwser

Comment: Ricardo Dias Morais ah i see, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a Checkbox from the Grial UIKit, but are defining the sender as the Native Xamarin.Forms CheckBox, use the Grial CheckBox as the Casting Class of the sender

```
//This will make every checkbox to checked or unchecked depending of the state of the clicked one
private void AllCheckBox_IsCheckedChanged(object sender, IsCheckedChangedEventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox ClickedCheckbox = sender as UXDivers.Grial.Checkbox;
    ChangeAllCheckboxesTo(ClickedCheckbox.IsChecked != null ? ClickedCheckbox.IsChecked : false);
}

//This will make every checkbox to false if you select one
private void AnyCheckBox_IsCheckedChanged(object sender, IsCheckedChangedEventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox ClickedCheckbox = sender as UXDivers.Grial.Checkbox;
    bool WasSelected = ClickedCheckbox.IsChecked != null ? ClickedCheckbox.IsChecked != null : false;
    ChangeAllCheckboxesTo(false);
    if(!WasSelected)
        ClickedCheckbox.IsChecked = true;
}

public void ChangeAllCheckboxesTo(bool value)
{
    try
    {
        UpperIntermediateCheckBox.IsChecked = value;
        AdvancedCheckBox.IsChecked = value;
        IntermediateCheckBox.IsChecked = value;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```